# Creating Pandas Dataframe from WebScraping Results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table from espn and send the data to a pandas dataframe in order to export it to excel. I have completed most of the scraping, but am getting stuck on how to send each 'td' tag to a unique dataframe cell within my for loop. (Code is below) Any thoughts? Thanks!

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup("http://www.espn.com/nba/statistics/player/_/stat/scoring-
per-game/sort/avgPoints/qualified/false")

regex = re.compile("^[e-o]")

for record in soup.findAll('tr', {"class":regex}):
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        print(data)
```

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4047084

Comment: What? The regex is there to remove the multiple headers that appear every n rows..

Comment: Where is the removal? You are applying regex on BeautifulSoup's parsing function, `findAll()`. Hence the above link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually recently scraping sports websites working on a daily fantasy sports algorithm for a class. This is the script I wrote up. Perhaps this approach can work for you. Build a dictionary. Convert it to a dataframe.

```
    url = http://www.footballdb.com/stats/stats.html?lg=NFL&yr={0}&type=reg&mode={1}&limit=all

    result = requests.get(url)
    c = result.content

    # Set as Beautiful Soup Object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c)

    # Go to the section of interest
    tables = soup.find("table",{'class':'statistics'})

    data = {}
    headers = {}
    for i, header in enumerate(tables.findAll('th')):
        data[i] = {}
        headers[i] = str(header.get_text())

    table = tables.find('tbody')
    for r, row in enumerate(table.select('tr')):
        for i, cell in enumerate(row.select('td')):
            try:
                data[i][r] = str(cell.get_text())
            except:
                stat = strip_non_ascii(cell.get_text())
                data[i][r] = stat

    for i, name in enumerate(tables.select('tbody .left .hidden-xs a')):
        data[0][i] = str(name.get_text())

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```